# Cool PostSharp aspects

Tags: c#, .net, aop, postsharp

I'm looking for interesting PostSharp aspects - anything that you found useful and wouldn't mind sharing.

Answer (score 4):

The coolest aspect of it for me is that it can help me implement the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

*"In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that all its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility."*

I hope to adopt this more fully with more experience in the future, but for now, I have just started with having it built in to my logging needs:

together with [Log4PostSharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp), I can do:

```
[Log(LogLevel.Info, "Counting characters.")]
int CountCharacters(string arg) {
   return arg.Length;
}
```

What this means is that, the responsibility of logging is ascribed elsewhere (coding wise), and injected from a separate source by PostSharp and Log4PostSharp magic.

Answer (score 4):

D. Patrick Caldwell has some cool ideas on his blog.

Validate Parameters Using Attributes and PostSharp
http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/03/validate-parameters-using-attributes.html

- Implmementing Coding Contracts using PostSharp.

Memoizer Attribute Using PostSharp
http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/02/memoizer-attribute-using-postsharp.html

- Basically, a light-weight field-value caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Daft question, but isn't that the purpose of the [Contributions Directory](http://www.postsharp.org/contributions)?

There is an example of automatic property-change implementation - [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged).

Comment: Actually, there's one in PostSharp's examples, but it's buggy. Had to rework that a little.